# How to unit test a service in angular that returns promise

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

```
public productanalysis(pID: number | string,  mainprod = false): Promise<dataArray[]> {
 return new Promise((success, error) => {
   this.api.seePro(pid).subscribe(res =>  {
     const d = this.mArray(res, mainprod);
     success(ingredients);
   });
 });
```

As per my understanding, we have to test 2 cases, 1. is to see in success case and another on false case.
2. how to write test case for success response case.

Comment: Can you show your test code?

Comment: it('should throw error if API if error occurs when analyzeIngredients is called', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(api, 'testprocess').and.returnValue(of({res: {ababab}} as any));
    const value = service.productanalysis('fchgfghf', false);
    expect(1).toBe(1);
    discardPeriodicTasks();
  }));

Comment: What is `testprocess`? Didn't you mean `seePro`? Please edit original post and provide coherent code.